# Не работают алиасы в vue cli

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue-cli, tsconfig

Проект пишу на **TypeScript**. Добавляю алиасы так:

```js
configureWebpack: {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      'Components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/сomponents'),
      'API': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/api'),
      'Mixins': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/mixins'),
    },
  },
},
```

Но получаю ошибку при сборке.

> This dependency was not found:
> Mixins/application/ApplicationMixin in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save Mixins/application/ApplicationMixin

Так же алиасы не видит **IDE**. Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как я потратил не мало времени, чтобы это заработало, то делюсь опытом. Может кому поможет и сократит время на настройку.

Для того чтобы работали алиасы(например: `Api`,`Components`) и их видел **IDE**(например, **PhpStorm**) сначало необходимо указать `paths` в `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"paths": {
  "@/*": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "Api/*": [
    "./src/api/*"
  ],
  "Components/*": [
    "./src/components/*"
  ]
},
```

А затем продублировать их в `vue.config.js`:

```js
configureWebpack: {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      'Components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/сomponents'),
      'API': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/api'),
      'Mixins': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/mixins'),
    },
  },
},
```

*Проверено на **@vue/cli 4.5.8**.*

Comment: ну так очевидно же! один для IDE(tsc) другой для webpack :)

Comment: "Проект пишу на TypeScript" - и что, TS in VUE наконец поддерживается? и в темплейтах и в компонентах? и автокомплит и проверка типов и рефакторинг?

Comment: @qwabra Я решил дать вопрос/ответ так как потратил прилично времени. Быть может кому-то пригодится.

Comment: @qwabra Проверка типов работает, автокомплит тоже. Например, недавно, подсказал, что я обращаюсь к приватному свойству.

Comment: А какой сетап? IDE, плагины - поделись пж. может статья какая есть на эту тему. Я примерно раз в год пытаюсь завести vue + ts на vscode +?оф. плагин - то не работает совсем, то работает частично, то работает а после перезапуска ломается ... На фоне богатого сайта и крутого комьюнити как-то странно это выглядит и сильно огорчает, особенно если сравнить со Svelte, который всего лишь в альфе или например полимером старым.

Comment: Всё по дефолту через `cli`. У меня шторм.